# how to hide a record in hierarchy model salesforce

Tags: security, sharing

I have a hierarchy model where 1 manager with 2 leads officer (A, B) and 2 sales person under each lead officer. Now my client need to hide records of A lead officer from manager. How can it be possible?

Answer (score 2):

Kindly have a look at "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" checkbox in sharing settings. Deselect Grant Access Using Hierarchies if you want to prevent users from gaining automatic access to data owned by or shared with their subordinates in the hierarchies.

But please note that :

1. Regardless of your organization's sharing settings, users can gain access to records they do not own through other means such as user permissions like “View All Data,” sharing rules, or manual sharing of individual records.
2. The Grant Access Using Hierarchies option is always selected on standard objects and is not editable.

So if its a standard object, your scenario is not realizable.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_controlling_access_using_hierarchies.htm&language=en_US